# Cuda for PyTorch and Cuda for Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, pytorch, cuda

I want to install PyTorch and for that I visited PyTorch official website, and they give me a command to install it with Cuda:

```
pip3 install torch==1.9.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 torchaudio===0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

The version of Cuda, they want me to install for PyTorch, is 11.1. But I already have Cuda install in my computer which is `Cuda 11.2` (for TensorFlow 2.5.0). My question is if I install PyTorch with that command they gave me, will it remove Cuda 11.2 ?
If it removed Cuda 11.2 and replace it with Cuda 11.1, then TensorFlow won't be able to run on GPU. Do I have to sacrifice TensorFlow in order to use PyTorch ? Is there any method to them keep both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to sort out your issue is to create virtual environments. Below are two ways to set up virtual environments

- `pip` virtual environment
- `conda` virtual environment

I suggest to go for setting up anaconda (`conda`) virtual environment for different versions of Tensorflow, Pytorch, CUDA

Follow this guide,
[Guide to conda for tensorflow and pytorch](https://towardsdatascience.com/guide-to-conda-for-tensorflow-and-pytorch-db69585e32b8)